# Not seeing the decimal from a string when converted into NSDecimalNumer

Tags: objective-c, xcode, nsstring, nsdecimalnumber

I can't see to find the answer to this, but I have a string that has a decimal point in it, and when I try to convert it to a NSDecimalNumber I only get back the whole number, not the decimal or what would come after it. This is what I am trying:

```
someText.text = @"200.00";
tempAmountOwed = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:someText.text]; // gives me back 200
```

I can't seem to figure out if the decimalNumberWithString method is stripping out my decimal and ignoring what comes after it.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Try it with @"200.45".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the method `decimalNumberWithString: locale:` method.

for eg:-

The code:

```
NSLog(@"%@", [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:@"200.00"]);
NSLog(@"%@", [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:@"200.00" locale:NSLocale.currentLocale]);
```

Gives following log:

```
200
200.00
```

Hope this Helps!

Comment: When I try this code I still get back 200 for both of those logs.

Answer (score 0):

That's perfectly normal. If your decimal String doesn't contain fractions it won't print them. If you want to print them you can use a `NSNumberFormatter` or convert it to a float and print it with `%.2f` to do so:

```
NSString *text = @"200.00";
NSDecimalNumber *number = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:text];
NSLog(@"%@", number); //this will print "200"

//solution #1
NSNumberFormatter *numberFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
numberFormatter.numberStyle = NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle;
numberFormatter.minimumFractionDigits = 2;
NSLog(@"%@", [numberFormatter stringFromNumber:number]); //this will print "200.00"

//solution #2
CGFloat number = [text floatValue];
NSLog(@"%.2f", number); //this will print "200.00"
```

Comment: I am trying to stay away from floats at I am dealing with currency and read about the down falls from using them. But thanks for the answer!

Comment: solution #1 works without floats, it works with NSDecimalNumbers as well as with NSNumbers. That's the way you should go.